# Id, url and natural key in django rest framework

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

Consider these models in Django:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

Now suppose you have created an API using Django Rest Framework to access these models. When accessing `http://my.site.com/api/model_b/1` to retrieve a `ModelB` instance, sometimes you'll want the `id` of related ModelA instance, i.e.:

```
{'id': 1, 'model_a': 17}
```

sometimes you'll want to get its `url`, i.e.:

```
{'id': 1, 'model_a': 'http://my.site.com/api/model_a/17'}
```

and other times its so called `natural key`, i.e.:

```
{'id': 1, 'model_a': 'some_representative_string_describing_the_instance'}
```

My question: is there a built-in feature that can handle the type of reference to `model_a` according to a get parameter, e.g.:

```
http://my.site.com/api/model_b/1?fk_type=id
http://my.site.com/api/model_b/1?fk_type=url
http://my.site.com/api/model_b/1?fk_type=natural_key
```

**UPDATE**: Also, I'd like to have finer control when `ModelB` has two or more foreign keys, allowing me to decide the type of encoding independently. Something like:

```
ModelBSerializer(model_b_instance, fk_encoding={'model_a': 'url', 'model_c': 'natural_key'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a different serializers for each type of serialization you want to use. And then override the [`get_serializer_class`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes). Something like the following:

```
#by default django serializes FK by id
class ModelBIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB


class ModelBUrlSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_a = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='model-a-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB


class ModelBNaturalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_a = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
```

And then inside `ModelBViewSet`

```
class ModelBViewSet():
    #...

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('fk_type') == 'url':
            return ModelBUrlSerializer
        elif self.request.GET.get('fk_type') == 'natural_key':
            return ModelBNaturalSerializer
        else:
            return ModelBIdSerializer
```

Comment: thx, but this doesn't completely satisfy me... I should create 3 different serializers each time I need this feature and serializers could be much more complicated than these, therefore I would have a lot of duplicated code to maintain. I was wondering about something more concise, perhaps implemented at serializer level and allowing finer control when ModelB has two or more fk (please see the update part in my question).